# Azure Machine Learning Studio - run a single prompt multiple times

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ai

Is there any way of running a single prompt flow with the same input multiple times (for example, 100 times) and creating the evaluation metrics based on all of the runs?
For example, I want to run a single prompt flow with the same inputs 100 times and then I want the output metrics to be calculated based on the accumulated outputs

Comment: Any approach you tried. If yes provide those details and error you are facing

Comment: @JayashankarGS I tried search in MS documentation and to play with the Machine Learning Studio without a success

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to run a single prompt flow with the same inputs multiple times and create evaluation metrics based on all of the runs. This can be achieved by using a batch run in Azure AI Studio.

To run a prompt flow multiple times with the same inputs, you can create a batch run and specify the number of times you want the flow to be executed. You can also upload the input data to the batch run settings.

After the batch run is completed, you can view the output metrics for each run in the Overview > Metrics tab. You can then aggregate the metrics across all runs to get the accumulated outputs.

You can checkout below documents:

[Customize evaluation flow and metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/prompt-flow/how-to-develop-an-evaluation-flow?view=azureml-api-2#customize-evaluation-flow-and-metrics)

[Develop an evaluation flow in Azure AI Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-studio/how-to/flow-develop-evaluation#develop-an-evaluation-flow-in-azure-ai-studio)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).